# Is there a suitable data structure for solving this question?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have four group of data:

```
//group 1
2 2 6
2 2 7
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 3 7

3 2 5
3 2 6
3 2 7
3 3 4
3 3 5
3 3 6
3 3 7
...
...
7 2 2
7 2 3
7 2 5
7 2 7
7 3 2
7 5 2
7 6 2

//group 2
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
2 2 5
2 3 2
2 3 3

3 3 2
3 3 3
3 4 2
...
...

5 2 2

//group 3
2 4
2 5

3 3
3 4
3 5
3 6
...
...
7 2

//group 4
6
7
8
```

And what I want to do is for given input number(s), give all the possible results.
A example might help to explain what I want to do:
Say input is 7, then the output should be the following:

```
from group 1
7 2 2
7 2 3
7 2 5
7 2 7
7 3 2
7 5 2
7 6 2

from group 2
//nothing

from group 3
7 2

from group 4
7
```

Then I add second input 2 (so the total input is 7 2), then the result should be

```
from group 1
7 2 2
7 2 3
7 2 5
7 2 7

from group 2
//nothing

from group 3
7 2

from group 4
//nothing
```

Then I add a 3rd input 5 (so the total input is 7 2 5), then the result should be

```
from group 1
7 2 5

from group 2
//nothing

from group 3
//nothing

from group 4
//nothing
```

It appears to be I need a forest(several trees) for this, correct ?
If so , is there any good c++ tree implementation of forest for this task or I better hand made one myself ?

Many Thanks

Comment: You need to actually describe the *algorithm* you are trying to use.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to output all the lines that contain your output as a prefix, right?

Comment: Looks like a *prefix tree*. There isn't one in the C++ standard library, but I'm sure you'll find a good implementation on the internet.

Comment: Sounds like a great job for a database.

Comment: @DeadMG: I think the algorithm would depend on which data structure I choose to use. Please let me know if my example is not clear enough.

Comment: @Giorgio: Basically it's kind of search and the result might not be unique. What I want for output is exactly what I described in the example.

Comment: If you just want to compute the output then you can just use a list of lists to represent the groups, and a list to represent the prefix. Then you scan the lists and filter out those that match. If you want to store all possible results at the same time, then you could use a prefix tree, as suggested by Kerrek SB.

Comment: What do you mean the result might not be unique? For given groups and prefix the result is unique, as far as I understand.

Comment: @Giorgio: 'unique' here I meant not one to one match, as the input increase, the possible matches will be reduced

Comment: Ah, ok, the same result could be retrieved from different groups, that's right.

Comment: @Giorgio: I haven't use prefix tree before, but just googling it seems to be the right concept for this task. What do you mean add a list to represent the prefix ?

Comment: The question is awful: *what I want to do is for given input number(s), give all the possible results*. What is the **problem** for which you want to produce the results? Described in plain english.

Comment: @Gob00st: You write "the total input is 7 2". This is the prefix you want to match. This can be represented as the list [7, 2]. Actually, when you build the tree, this will correspond to a path from the root of the tree to a given node.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs ! Prefix tree should be the official solution but Nim's answer is a practical one using existing STL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like to hold the data

```
std::set<std::vector<int> > data;
```

Now you can create one of these for each group if there is no guarantee that the number of items in each group is the same, or if you know what each group is a specific number of items, then put them all in the same set.

Then use `std::find_if` with a custom predicate with the above `data`. And in this predicate have a `std::vector` which is the sequence you are looking for.

```
struct search_sequence
{
  bool operator()(std::vector<int> const& cVal) const
  {
    if (sequence.size() <= cVal.size())
      return std::equal(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), cVal.begin());
    return false;
  }

  std::vector<int> sequence;
};
```

Now applying this with `std::find_if` will find all sequences in `data` which start with the search sequence.

EDIT: To store in the single instance, wrap the vector, e.g.

```
struct group_entry
{
  int id;
  std::vector<int> data;

  friend bool operator<(group_entry const& lhs, group_entry const& rhs)
  {
    return lhs.id < rhs.id && lhs.data < rhs.data;
  }
};
```

Now your set contains

```
std::set<group_entry> data;
```

Add all the data from all the groups

Modify the predicate:

```
struct search_sequence
{
  bool operator()(group_entry const& cVal) const
  {
    if (sequence.size() <= cVal.data.size())
      return std::equal(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), cVal.data.begin());
    return false;
  }

  std::vector<int> sequence;
};
```

Comment: Those 4 group of data is NOT the same, e.g. group one & two always have 3 elements, group three always have 2 elements and group 4 always have 1 element.

Comment: @Gob00st, fine, in that case have an instance of `data` for each group. And do `find_if` on each group...

Comment: I know I can do the searchs for 4 groups before I asked this question. I am just wondering intead of doing 4 searchs each time, can I use one data structure to hold the overall data and just do one search each time ?

Comment: @Gob00st: Ok then I think a prefix tree is what you need. At each node you can put a list of results for that node.

Comment: @Giorgio: So far prefix tree sounds like the right way, but I have many different inputs, input could start with 4 or 5. So I might need a forest of prefix trees ?

Comment: You can also say that the root corresponds to the empty prefix, each child to the first element, and so on.

Comment: @Nim: I realize your answer was already accepted, but I just realized `std::set::find_lower_bound()` and `std::set::find_upper_bound()` would be significantly faster than `std::find_if()`.

Comment: @Mooing Duck, I don't think it makes any difference for `std::set`, those two operations are logarithmic if you pass in a *random access iterator*, however set has *forward* or *reverse* iterators...

Comment: @Nim: That is true for std::lower_bound, but std::set::find_lower_bound() is logarithmic for set::iterators.  (easy mistake)

Comment: @Mooing, ahh, I was not aware of them... need to look at the reference again.... thx.

Answer (score 3):

A "forest of trees" in c++ terms would be:

```
vector<set<string> >
```

Where the strings in the set are "2 2 6", "2 2 7", etc.

Assuming you only want to use prefixes, and all numbers are one digit (or zero justified to the same width), you could implement the algorithm with [set::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/lower_bound/) and [set::upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/upper_bound/) on the prefix you want (in the example, first "7" then "7 2", etc).

Example:

```
void PrintResults(const vector<set<string> >& input, const string& prefix) {
  for (int i = 0, end(input.size()); i < end; ++i) {
    cout << "from group " << i + 1 << endl;
    const set<string>& group_set = input[i];
    set<string>::const_iterator low(group_set.lower_bound(prefix)), high(group_set.upper_bound(prefix));
    if (low == high) {
      cout << "//nothing" << endl;
    } else {
      for (; low != high; ++low) {
        cout << *low << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could use a vector of tries for this, but there isn't a std library version.

Answer (score 2):

Since the depth appears to be fixed

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, std::set<int> > >
```

would do the job. Not sure it's worth it given the number of data items though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sketch of a possible solution:

```
class Group
{
    int id;

    std::vector<int> values;
}
```

You use this class to store both an entire group (the initial data), and the result of a query (content of a group after applying some filter).

A tree is constructed using nodes and edges; each node uses a vector of Group to store the result for that node.

```
class Node;

typedef Node *NodePtr;

class Edge
{
    NodePtr target;

    int value;
};

class Node
{
    // Results for each group. Maybe empty for certain groups.
    // Contains all elements for all groups in the root node.
    std::vector<Group> results;

    std::vector<Edge> children;
};
```

When you search, you start at the root. To match, e.g. 7 2, you look for a child of the root that is reached by traversing an edge with value == 7. Then you look at the target node of that edge, and you look for an edge with value == 2. When you reach the final node of the path, you have the result in the results vector.

**Update**
Of course you also have the problem of constructing such a tree. You can do it using a recursive algorithm.

You start with the root node containing all the groups and all the lists. Then, for each first element of a list, you add an edge with a corresponding node and the corresponding result set.

You repeat the above step for each child node, this time looking at the second elements in the lists. And so on until you cannot extend the tree any more.

Answer (score 2):

As other posters have said, you want a prefix tree.  Here's a simple sample to get you started, assuming the only characters are 0-7.  Note that I put in very little safety, and number assumes that strings given to it are all followed by spaces (EVEN THE LAST ONE), and results are returned the same way (it's easier).  For real code, more safety should be involved.  Also, code is uncompiled/untested, so probably has errors.

```
class number { //create a prefix node type
    number& operator=(const number& b); //UNDEFINED, NO COPY
    int endgroup;  //if this node is the end of a string, this says which group
    number* next[8];  // pointers to nodes of the next letter
public:
    number() :group(-1) { //constructor
        for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
            next[i] = nullptr;
    }
    ~number() { // destructor
        for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
            delete next[i];
    }
    void add(char* numbers, int group) { //add a string to the tree for a group
        if(next[numbers[0] == '\0') //if the string is completely used, this is an end
            endgroup = group;
        else {
            int index = numbers[0]-'0'; //otherwise, get next letter's node
            if (next[index] == nullptr)
                next[index] = new number; //and go there
            next[index].add(numbers+2, group); //+2 for the space
        }
    }
    void find(char* numbers, 
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>& out, 
        std::string sofar="") 
    { //find all strings that match
        if(numbers[0]) { //if there's more letters 
            sofar.append(numbers[0]).append(' '); //keep track of "result" thus far
            int index = numbers[0]-'0'; //find next letter's node
            if (next[index] == nullptr)
                return; //no strings match
            next[index].find(numbers+2, out, sofar); //go to next letter's node
        } else { //if there's no more letters, return everything!
            if (endgroup > -1) //if this is an endpoint, put it in results
                out.push_back(std::pair<int, std::string>(endgroup, sofar));
            for(int i=0; i<8; ++i) { //otherwise, try all subsequent letter combinations
                if (next[i]) {
                    std::string try(sofar);  //keep track of "result" thus far
                    try.append('0'+i).append(' ');
                    next[i].find(numbers, out, try); //try this letter
                }
            }
        }
    }
} root; //this is your handle to the tree

int main() {
    //group one
    root.add("2 2 6", 1);
    root.add("2 2 7", 1);
    //...
    //group two
    root.add("2 2 2", 2);
    //...

    std::string pattern;
    char digit;
    while(true) {
        std::cin >> digit;
        if (digit<'0' || digit > '7')
            break;
        pattern.append(digit).append(' ');
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> results;
        root.find(pattern.c_str(), results);
        for(int g=1; g<4; ++g) {
            std::cout << "group " << g << "\n";
            for(int i=0; i<results.size(); ++i) {
                if( results.first == g)
                    std::cout << results.second;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of strings will do the trick. Each line is a string. You might decorate the lines with separators to make the search easier, like "/7/2/2/" instead of "7 2 2" so you can search for "/2".

My guess is your professor wants you to use a more complex data structure.