# Suffix Range c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

I am trying to build a Suffix range that is

if I have  strings "catalog" "catalyst" "ban" "bany"

then suffix tree will be like

```
                            .
                           / \
                          c   b
                         /     \
                        a       a
                       /         \
                      t           n
                     / \         / \        
                    a   a       $   y 
                   /     \         / \
                  l       l       $    $
                 /         \
                o           y         
               /             \
              g               s
             / \               \
            $   $               t
                                /\
                               $   $
```

I want to find Suffix range of each string now .. that if I take string "Cat" then it should give me a range enclosing all its suffixes to which "cat" is a prefix. I need to use sentinels to separate each string.. may be a "$"

Can any one suggest me a best way to find out this using c++ . Any references will be helpfull. thank you

Comment: What have you tried? This is actually a pretty cool concept though, I've never heard of a suffix range.

Comment: Why do "catalog" and "catalyst" diverge at "t" instead of "l"?

Comment: Is this different from a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_tree)?

Comment: @seth Carnegie I was thinking If I have suffix array and I will lexicographically sorted range and will store it in integer array .. then for each string from input i was thinking to get range . which includes all its suffixes.. I think binary searching for each may work but I am not good at programming ..so wanted to seek some help

Comment: I like the suggestion by Kerrek. I used 'prefix tree' in google and got http://whiteboxcomputing.com/java/prefix_tree/

Comment: @marcelo .. sory thats a mistake ..ya it should diverge at "l"

Comment: The data structure you've described here is a trie, not a suffix tree.

Comment: Check my new answer. Upvote(shameless-me) if you liked it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is, I guess, the most concise answer. :)

```
set<string> s;
string word = "ABC"
//Inserts.
// e.g. s.insert("ABCD");

for(set<string>::iterator it=s.begin();it!=s.end();++it)
    if(!(*it).compare(0,word.size(),word))
        cout<<*it<<endl;
```

Tested code! :P

Comment: Just a comment about whats happening in Hood.
1. set is stored as height-balanced binary search tree.
2. When we go from  set.begin() to set.end() : we are kind of doing a in order traversal of the tree.
3. Time complexity of the code I wrote is O(n) every node will be visited. It could be improved by adding a condition 
 if((*it).substring(0,sizeOfWord) > word) break;
4. I donno if they are actually storing the end nodes in B+ tree fashion to make in-order traversal really efficient. Someone can digg it please.

Comment: Nichole said there's some 10000 strings, and you're code checks EACH AND EVERY ONE OF THEM.

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler answer than my first.  You have a std::set of strings:

```
typedef std::set<std::string>::iterator iter_type;
std::set<std::string> data;
```

and a function named find() which returns a pair of iterators.  The first iterator points at the beginning of the strings that match the prefix, and the last iterator is one past the last string that matches the prefix.  If you have 10000 strings, this needs to only check about 26 of them.

```
std::pair<iter_type, iter_type> find(std::string substr) {
   std::pair<iter_type, iter_type> r;
   r.first = data.lower_bound(substr);
   substr[substr.size()-1]++; //I'm assuming substr is at least one character
   r.second = data.upper_bound(substr);
   return r;
}
```

Then, after the data has been loaded, you merely call the find(...) function, and it returns a pair of iterators pointing at the strings you want.  You can use these as inputs to any standard algorithm, or do whatever.

```
int main() {
    data.insert("catalog");
    data.insert("catalyst");
    data.insert("ban");
    data.insert("bany");
    //find the region of strings beginning with "cat"
    std::pair<iter_type, iter_type> range = find("cat");
    //display them all
    for(iter_type i=range.first; i!=range.second; ++i)
        std::cout << *i << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 : 
Space efficient
Use Trie  data structure (one-char is one node, one node can point to 26 different nodes)
 Find the last-node for given prefix.
 Print  prefix+'path to all terminal nodes'

Solution 2 :
Time efficient
say you are interested in only first 3 prefix chars. Create a 3d array

```
 vector<string> arr[27][27][27]
```

Insert . if you want to insert
word : ABCD      arr[A][B][C].push_back("D")
word : BBBX      arr[B][B][B].push_back("X")

Print : 
   vector & a = arr[char1][char2][char3]
   for( string s in a)
        char1-char2-char3+ s

Answer (score 0):

I posted an algorithm to solve a remarkably similar problem at [Is there a suitable data structure for solving this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123785/is-there-a-suitable-data-structure-for-solving-this-question/7124982#7124982).  First, we create a suffix tree of nodes similar to

```
class node { //create a prefix node type
    node & operator=(const node & b); //UNDEFINED, NO COPY
    node & operator=(const node && b); //UNDEFINED, NO COPY
    node * next[27];  // pointers to nodes of the next letter (27th letter is $)
public:
    node(); 
    ~node();
    void add(char* mystring);
    void find(char* mystring, 
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>& out, 
        std::string sofar="");
}root;
```

And fill it.  Then, to find all the substrings of "cata", we iterate through the tree according to the letters in "cata" (root[3]->[0]->['t'-'a'?]->[0]), and keep track of the string `sofar`.  When we reach the end of `mystring`, we recursively try going down each child, instead of just the ones that match the substring, and wherever we find 'end' (letter 27), we push `sofar` onto `out`.  Then we simply return, and `out` holds all the full strings beginning with "cata".

Comment: The solution is perfect but If the input data is large(~30000 character/ 10000 words), then it will take long time to walk through each node .Can you suggest me any time and space efficient method

Comment: Whoa!  30000 characters EACH?, or 3 characters average?